# CakePHP Router::connect and regex

Tags: php, regex, cakephp

I'm having some trouble with redirection in config/routes.php file

I can't find the right regex

```
$_skill = '[A-Za-z\-]+'

Router::connect('/-:skill/:city-:zipcode:shit', array('controller' => 'redirects', 'action' => 'district'),
                    array('city' => '[A-Za-z-0-9\]+.(er|eme)-arrondissement',
                          'skill' => $_skill,
                          'zipcode' => $_zipcode,
                          'shit' => '(.*)',
                          'pass' => array('zipcode'),
                          )
                    );
```

I would like to match any url where city ends with 'arrondissement' but i'm a total noob in regex

thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With most regex you can use the dollar symbol to match the end of a string.

simply `'arrondissement$'`

And drop all the stuff at the beginning.